# Amp form custom validation doesn't work in android browser

Tags: android, validation, mobile, amp-html

I'm using amp-form custom validation in my website. Desktop chrome and safari browsers work well in custom validation. iPhone safari works too but required https. When I tested on android chrome browser, the custom validation didn't work, but only show the HTML5 form validation pop up required field. The outcome is not what I expect. I had tried amp-html demo page on android chrome browser, it shows HTML5 form validation instead of custom validation.

**Form Jade**

```
input.form-control.validate(type="text",placeholder="Full name in NRIC*", required, id="inputNameField", pattern="...")
   span.amp-form-validator(visible-when-invalid="patternMismatch" validation-for="inputNameField")
     | Name is required (Maximum 35 characters only)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same post in this [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/webmasters/tGqcU11d21I/0gaR9oX4BwAJ).

I have tried running the link: https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/random888/forms.amp.html using Nexus 6 Chrome browser and it is working fine as compared to the screenshot you provided in the link above.

[image: Screenshot]

You may try checking it again.

Comment: I'm tested on Android version 6.0.1 and Google Chrome 55.0.2883.91, still not working.. appear to be pop up validation.